# Картинки фиксированой длины, контент с blur не видно при наведении

Tags: html, css

При загрузке картинок разной длины мне нужен один и тот же размер к примеру
`208px x 208px`. Но при адаптивности например этот размер то маленький, то большой. Как правильно адаптировать картинки высоту и длину, и можно ли это сделать с помощью `%` что бы не писать нужный размер и `margin` при разных размерах экрана? Еще контент `div'a` не видит `blur: hover` при наведении на картинку, как исправить?

```css
.service-item-price {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", sans-serif !important;
  text-align: center !important;
}

.service-item-price span {
  color: $primary-color !important;
  &-price {
    color: $primary-color !important;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }
}

.service-item {
  margin-left: 4px;
  margin-right: 4px;
  h4 {
    margin-top: 15px;
    text-align: center !important;
    font-size: 17px !important;
  }
  &:hover {
    .service-item-image {
      .v-btn {
        opacity: 1;
        top: 45%;
      }
      &::before {
        border-radius: 17px;
        opacity: .6;
      }
    }
  }
  &-image {
    min-height: max-content !important;
    background-size: cover !important;
    position: relative !important;
    img {
      width: 100%;
      border: 2px solid #FFEBF6;
      border-radius: 19px;
      object-fit: cover;
      &:hover {
        filter: blur(4px);
      }
    }
    .v-btn {
      font-size: 14px !important;
      position: absolute !important;
      left: 10% !important;
      height: 55px !important;
      width: 80%;
      top: 80%;
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transition: all .5s;
      -o-transition: all .5s;
      transition: all .5s;
      &:after {
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }
    &:before {
      position: absolute;
      content: '';
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      background-color: $primary-color;
      opacity: 0;
      transition: all .5s ease;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="service-item">
  <div class="service-item-image">
    <img src="{{url('/storage/'.$product->getImages()[0])}}" alt="Alt">
    <v-btn outlined itemprop="url" href="{{$product->link}}" rounded color="white">Skonfiguruj zamówienia</v-btn>
  </div>
  <div class="service-item-price">
    <h4>{{$product->name}}</h4>
    <span class="price" content="{{$product->calculated}}">
            Od {{$product->calculated}}<span>&nbsp; zł / 100 szt.</span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```